# How to diagnose errors in LaTeX generated by Doxygen 1.8.x: LT@LL@FM@cr

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex

I've been using Doxygen successfully to generate PDF documentation for a sizable Fortran 90 project since v1.6. After a recent upgrade to Doxygen 1.8, pdflatex is choking with an error I can't understand. From refman.log:

```
.
.
.
<use classfate__source_a022bf629bdc1d3059ebd5fb86d13b4f4_icgraph.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: classfate__source_a022bf629bdc1d3059ebd5fb86d13b4f4_ic
graph.pdf used on input line 607.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 350.0pt x 65.42921pt.
)
(./classm__aerosol.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \LT@LL@FM@cr 

l.25 ...1833ffa6f2fae54ededb}{ia\-\_\-nsize}), \\*

? ?
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
```

Looking at the first 25 lines of classm__aerosol.tex, nothing obviously matches the error message:

```
\hypertarget{classm__aerosol}{\section{m\-\_\-aerosol Module Reference}
\label{classm__aerosol}\index{m\-\_\-aerosol@{m\-\_\-aerosol}}
}


Contains general aerosol-\/related constants and routines.  


\subsection*{Public Member Functions}
\begin{DoxyCompactItemize}
\item 
subroutine \hyperlink{classm__aerosol_aa06c1f39c6bd34f22be92d21535f0320}{aerdis} (I\-A\-E\-R\-O, M\-A\-E\-R\-O, V\-O\-L, A\-R\-E\-A, M\-U, T\-G\-A\-S, R\-H\-O, A\-G\-A\-M\-M\-A, X\-L\-A\-E\-R, D\-M\-E\-A\-N, N\-A\-E\-R, X\-N\-D\-A\-E\-R, L\-S\-D\-A\-E\-R)
\begin{DoxyCompactList}\small\item\em Return aerosol mass given a volume, based on aerosol size distribution function. \end{DoxyCompactList}\item 
real(kind=wp) function \hyperlink{classm__aerosol_a2dff4ff413057e8788fba7270a30c093}{lamsed} (V\-O\-L, H, M\-U\-G, R\-H\-O\-A\-E\-R, A\-G\-A\-M\-M\-A, A\-C\-H\-I, A\-F\-E\-O, K\-O, M\-A\-E\-R, F\-M\-A\-E\-R, F\-A\-E\-R\-S\-S, F\-S\-E\-D\-D\-K)
\begin{DoxyCompactList}\small\item\em Calculate aerosol removal constant and interpolation factor between steady-\/state and decaying aerosol correlations. \end{DoxyCompactList}\item 
pure real(kind=wp) function \hyperlink{classm__aerosol_a6d0a04004f49c404c67e0aa69dd39ee1}{fdbend} (V\-E\-L, H\-S\-E\-D, T\-G, R\-H\-O\-G, M\-U\-G, R\-H\-O\-P\-A\-R, C\-A\-E\-R\-O, X\-D\-B\-E\-N\-D, N90\-J)
\begin{DoxyCompactList}\small\item\em Find total impaction efficiency for aerosol deposition considering 90-\/degree bends in a flow path. \end{DoxyCompactList}\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
\subsection*{Public Attributes}
\begin{DoxyCompactItemize}
\item 
integer, parameter \hyperlink{classm__aerosol_a8f604b7ffe3c1833ffa6f2fae54ededb}{ia\-\_\-nsize} = 30
\item 
integer, parameter \hyperlink{classm__aerosol_ae71813ecf0c7768af9d6292efb14774f}{ia\-\_\-nmass} = 10
\item 
real(kind=wp), dimension(\hyperlink{classm__aerosol_a8f604b7ffe3c1833ffa6f2fae54ededb}{ia\-\_\-nsize}), \\*
```

Nothing obviously matches the recently read chunk "\LT@LL@FM@cr" and I don't know enough low-level TeX to translate that into something that might actually be in the source text.

Suspecting this might have been fixed in a later version of Doxygen than the one shipping with Linux Mint (v1.8.1.2), I built & installed v1.8.3.1 from source, updated my doxyfile, blew away the old documentation and regenerated it. I get the same baffling error.

There's nothing obvious in refman.log that would indicate missing or broken LaTeX packages and I'm completely at a loss as to what's causing this.

Comment: Start with adding `\errorcontextlines=9999` to the head of the TeX file and rerun TeX, then update the answer with the extended error message. But IMHO this should be addressed to the doxygen authors.

Answer (score 2):

this will be difficult to solve unless you provide a bit more information - possibly using `\errorcontextlines=9999` as suggested in the comments on the question.

as a first short though, the name of the control sequence that can't be found (i.e. `\LT@LL@FM@cr`) is one defined by the [longtable package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) ([documentation](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf), p. 15) - thus adding:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

to the preamble of the document might help.

If so, according to the doxygen documentation [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extra_packages), adding the following to your configuration file should do the trick:

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES=longtable
```

Answer (score 2):

As this still gets a hit on Google when you search:
`doxygen missing $ inserted`
I would like to add something.

Do not use a PROJECT_NAME containing underscores (`_`)!

After a brief look into the doxygen's  current documentation (I am using 1.8.4) it does not make that explicit.